# Does multipath apply to sub-1kHz signals?

Tags: rf, wireless

Based on my (currently naive) understanding of EM field propagation, it would seem that in the near field (e.g. <10m), low frequency (e.g. sub-1kHz) signals would be oscillating so slow such that any discrepancies in the time to reach the receiver from different paths (due to speed of light) would be negligible.

Is this true?

Comment: Only you know that. You might be misdirecting us and actually believe something entirely different.

Comment: What are you asking?  Near field is the non-radiative portion of an EM field and propagation is not the same as a far-field EM wave.

Comment: Okay, I guess I wasn't clear.  I'm asking if a receiver in the (very) near field needs to consider multipath effects for low frequency signals.

Comment: What wavelength is 3kHz in km?  Then any multiples of that <10 is near yet so far away unless under water then less far

Comment: Wavelength of 3kHz ~100km, wavelength of 1kHz ~300km.

Answer (score 2):

Disturbances in the EM field due to source oscillations propagate at the speed of light (3e8 m/s).

For a 1kHz (300km wavelength) signal received at 10m, and assuming a very conservative worst case delay path of 40m, the worst case multipath delay will be (40-10)/(3e8) = 1e-7s (100ns) in time.

Assuming a sinusoidal wave with amplitude A (and also therefore max derivative A), the maximum signal inaccuracy will be 1e-7*A/A = 1e-5% = 100ppb.

These calculations do not take into account the constructive/destructive interference of multiple multipath components (not sure how to estimate that?), but overall, the worst case time delay (100ns) and inaccuracy (100ppb) delay for a given multipath component seems negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Multipath Losses depends on the carrier frequency not the modulation however  for acoustic frequency is certainly below 1 kHz and multi-path phasing affects the amplitude or quality of your bass reflex or subwoofer depending on the location in the room.

But if the Raleigh losses and/or the phase cancellation losses called Ricean Loss dropout the carrier it affects all f modulation

Comment: I thought the question was about EM fields, not sound.  Your answer appears to be about sound.

Comment: It refers to both

Comment: Okay, interesting.  I will consider this.  Note that I am referring to carrier (not modulation) frequency.

Comment: What application ? ELF ?

Comment: Yes, understanding the signal propagation on the order of power line frequencies.

Comment: magnetic fields dont usually travel that far with power line f due to friis loss, so it is irrelevant, I think.